# Estimating Required Sample Size based on Percentages

Tags: descriptive-statistics

The seeds of the garden pea are either yellow or green. A certain cross between pea plants produces progeny where 75% are plants with yellow seeds and 25% are plants with green seeds. What is the minimum number of progeny you would need to grow to have probability no less than 0.99 of obtaining at least 10 plants with green seeds?

I understand how to estimate a required sample size when I have data such as standard deviation, mean, correlation, etc., but I don't even know where to start to estimate it based on the percentage values with a certain probability.

Comment: Try to model it with a known family of probability distributions -- and argue that it makes sense before solving the problem (e.g., can you assume each of the plant offspring is independent of the others?). For a start, are you familiar with the Binomial distribution?

Comment: I am familiar with it, and using SAS I ran a binomial test that estimates sample size given power, but I'm unsure of the math behind it so I can't say whether or not it's correct. I'm not sure how to work obtaining at least 10 plants with green seeds into the estimation.